# XAML - TextBox Linebreak

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox

Is there anyway in XAML only to have a linebreak in a TextBox?

I know I can set myTextBox.Text = "something\r\nsomething2" in Code, but I can't do this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox">
    <TextBox.Text>
        Something
        <Linebreak/>
        Something2
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

or this

```
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" Text="something\r\nsomething2" />
```

Comment: As per @Dillie-O's reply, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183406/xaml-newline-in-string-attribute

Comment: Regardless of the OP's intent, this isn't an exact duplicate at all...He's asking about a TextBOX, not a TextBLOCK - which don't function the same when it comes to using <LineBreak />. I think this question should be reopened for potential answer/clarification or referred to a question that is actually a duplicate.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try using `&#x0a;` to replicate a `\r\n` like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" Text="something&#x0a;something2" />
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183406/xaml-newline-in-string-attribute)

Comment: Interesting. The #x0a; syntax works inside the literal "Text=" attribute, but not if you embed it inside of the <TextBox.Text> element.

Comment: @Matt: Yes I've observed this behavior as well. I'm not entirely sure why though.

Comment: You can use <TextBox xml:space="preserve"> to place the text within the element.

Comment: @RQDQ: Post your comment as a separate answer. I haven't seen this problem addressed anywhere else.