# WPF linebreak problems

Tags: wpf, textblock, line-breaks

I have a TextBlock and want to show information from the database.
I wan't to display the text like this:

```
Task for Day xy
- blabla
- blabla 
- more blablabla
```

Somehow I need to include a character for the newlines.. I thoug about \n.. so the text in the database would look like:

Task for Day xy\n- blabla\n- blabla\n- more blablabla

doesn't work.

I tried and searched online for hours.. no solution how to do that.
Also this doesn't work:

```
Task for Day xy<LineBreak />- blabla<LineBreak />- blabla<LineBreak />- more blablabla
```

the application shows exactly that string from the database without new lines..

here the part of the xaml:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}}" Margin="6" />
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Notes}" Margin="6" />
</Grid>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183406/xaml-newline-in-string-attribute

Comment: @Dylan: I disagree: The text from the text block is not a XAML literal, but rather a data-bound string.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend storing the line breaks in the database, as line breaks will not be the same across platforms.  I would just add the line breaks before displaying using System.Environment.NewLine.

Comment: Well, if you're using WPF, platform independence is a bit hard to achieve anyway...

Comment: True, but the data is not guaranteed to be only consumed from WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Just include a regular newline character in the text, no fancy escape sequences or XML tags:

```
 string fromDb = ... // get string from DB
 myPropertyWhichIsBoundToWpf = fromDb.Replace("hereShouldBeALinebreak", 
                                              System.Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: thank you, I thougt about something like this.
just hoped there was a better solution

Comment: @patricci: An alternative would be to create a Converter that adds the newline for you. That way, you can bind the data directly without adding a new property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx