# LineBreaks in WCF bound textblock

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, binding, textblock

I am pulling data from a previous page which was a selected item in a listbox from a wcf service.

Ther error I am having is that the textblock is not reading the formatting in my in my data.

this is the code that brings the data in from the previous page

```
private void LoadPlayer()
    {
        FrameworkElement root1 = Application.Current.RootVisual as FrameworkElement;
        var currentPlayer = root1.DataContext as PlayerProfile;
        _SelectedPlayer = currentPlayer;
    }
```

this is the xaml

```
<TextBlock Height="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="Blurb" Text="{Binding Bio}" xml:space="preserve" />
```

specifically I am trying to get the \r\n to work in my display as a linebreak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer here:

[Newline in string attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183406/xaml-newline-in-string-attribute)

In your case what you need to do write a Converter (something that implements IValueConverter) that turns the string data that contains the \r\n into encoded entities i.e.  and 
. Then just use that converter on your Binding.

```
public class EncodeCRLFConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    string stringtoconvert = value as string;

    if (input != null))
    {
        // Note there are different ways to do the replacement, this is
        // just a very simplistic method.

        stringtoconvert = stringtoconvert.Replace( "\r", "&#x0d;" );
        stringtoconvert = stringtoconvert.Replace( "\n", "&#x0a;" );

        return stringtoconvert;
    }
    return null;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
  }
}
```

Create an instance of your converter somewhere...e.g. typically in .Resources....(in this example I've just used Window because I don't know what your TextBlock is inside).

```
<Window.Resources>
<EncodeCRLFConverter x:Key="strconv"/>
<Window.Resources>

<TextBlock Height="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="Blurb" Text="{Binding Bio, Converter={StaticResource strconv}}" />
```