# Newline or carriage returns in Multibind StringFormat

Tags: wpf, xaml, textblock, multibinding

So i've got the following:

```
<TextBlock.Text>
  <MultiBinding StringFormat="So and so will donate {0:C0}&#x0d;&#x0a;to {1}, bringing the&#x0d;&#x0a;total amount to {2:C0}.">
    <Binding Path="VisitorTotal" />
    <Binding Path="EventName" />
    <Binding Path="EventTotal" />
  </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

I've tried `&#x0d;&#x0a;`, `&#10;`, `\n`, `\\n`, and various combinations thereto. Nothing will give me a newline. What's the deal?

Comment: Just `&#x0a;` *should* work - Can you show the full declaration of the TextBlock?  Do you have it set to wrap?

Comment: I do have it set to wrap actually. Interesting that that would have an effect.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

My preference is to use `Environment.NewLine` directly:

```
<MultiBinding StringFormat="So and so will donate {0:C0}{3}to {1}, bringing the{3}total amount to {2:C0}.">
  <Binding Path="VisitorTotal" />
  <Binding Path="EventName" />
  <Binding Path="EventTotal" />
  <Binding Source="{x:Static System:Environment.NewLine}"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

However, you'll also need to make sure the [`TextBlock.TextWrapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textwrapping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is set appropriately.

Comment: Awesome. Clever. Impeccable.

Comment: With adding  xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" for <Binding Source="{x:Static s:Environment.NewLine}"/> ( I change System to s to avoid multiple "System" words in the namespace definition ). Stolen from LPL answer in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183406/xaml-newline-in-string-attribute)