# Cannot get a line break to work with ToolTipService.ToolTip

Tags: c#, sql, silverlight, telerik, newline

So I'm using **Silverlight 4** and the **Telerik RadGridView**.

I've got the following **GridViewColumn**:

```xaml
<telerik:GridViewColumn UniqueName="CreditIssuesText"
                        CellStyle="{StaticResource rgvCellStyle}"
                        HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource rgvHeaderCellStyle}"
                        HeaderTextAlignment="Center"
                        TextAlignment="Center"
                        Width="Auto">
    <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="/HubSilverlight;component/Images/status_icon_info.png"
                   ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding CreditIssuesText}"
                   Visibility="{Binding CreditIssuesText, Converter={StaticResource TextToVisibilityConverter}}"
                   Width="16"
                   Height="16" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewColumn>
```

`CreditIssuesText` is being pulled from our SQL Server where a function concatenates all of the possible credit issues and joins them together with line breaks to be used in a tooltip when hovering over the icon.

I've already tried everything in **[Newline in string attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/183406/682480)** to no avail.

- `&#x0a;`
- `&#x0d;`
- `&#x0a;&#x0d;`
- `&#10;`
- `&#13;`
- `&#10;&#13;`
- `<br />`
- `<LineBreak />`
- `\n`
- `\r\n`

How in the world do I get a line break or newline to work in a bound string that's being pulled from SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I figured out what the issue was ...

In our SQL database, we store line breaks as `\n`. I have no idea why or how, but somewhere between the time the data was retrieved from SQL via our WCF service and the time the data was bound to the `GridView`, the tooltip string was being modified.  All of the `\n` line breaks were being escaped changing them to `\\n`.

What I ended up doing to resolve that issue was make a simple converter that replaced `\\n` with `Environment.NewLine`:

```cs
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var s = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        s = value.ToString().Trim().Replace("\\n", Environment.NewLine);
    }
    catch
    {
        // value is most likely null;
    }

    return s;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Then, I simply had to change the `ToolTipService.ToolTip` property value of the `Image` to:

```xaml
 <Image Source="/HubSilverlight;component/Images/status_icon_info.png"
        ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding CreditIssuesText, Converter={StaticResource NewLineConverter}}"
        Visibility="{Binding CreditIssuesText, Converter={StaticResource TextToVisibilityConverter}}"
        Width="16"
        Height="16" />
```

---

### This was great, but it brought up *another* issue ...

The tooltip only showed when you hovered over the `Image` in the cell. The desired effect was to show the tooltip when you hovered over *any* part of the cell.

***[@HeenaPatil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21163942/682480)*** pointed me in the right direction to resolve *that* issue.

The solution was to use a `TextBlock` inside of the `GridViewColumn.ToolTipTemplate` property where I bound the tooltip text to the `TextBlock.Text` property:

```xaml
<telerik:GridViewColumn UniqueName="CreditIssuesText"
                        CellStyle="{StaticResource rgvCellStyle}"
                        HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource rgvHeaderCellStyle}"
                        HeaderTextAlignment="Center"
                        TextAlignment="Center"
                        Width="Auto">
    
    <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="/HubSilverlight;component/Images/status_icon_info.png"
                   Visibility="{Binding CreditIssuesText, Converter={StaticResource TextToVisibilityConverter}}"
                   Width="16"
                   Height="16" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    
    <telerik:GridViewColumn.ToolTipTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CreditIssuesText, Converter={StaticResource NewLineConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>    
    </telerik:GridViewColumn.ToolTipTemplate>
    
</telerik:GridViewColumn>
```

---

### Again, this was great, but it brought up *yet another* issue ...

I was trying to get the tooltip to show at the bottom of the cell, but it was not respecting the `ToolTip.Placement` value no matter where I put the property, whether it was on the `TextBlock`, `Image`, `GridViewColumn`, or anywhere else.

What I ended up having to do was replace the `GridViewColumn.CellTemplate` and `GridViewColumn.ToolTipTemplate` with `GridViewColumn.CellStyle` so that I could use its `Template` property to wrap the `Image` in a `Border` object where I moved the `ToolTipService.ToolTip` and `ToolTipService.Placement` properties to.

Once I did that, the tooltip showed when you hovered over any part of the cell, it respected the placement value and was positioned at the bottom of the cell, and the line breaks remained intact:

```xaml
<telerik:GridViewColumn UniqueName="CreditIssuesText"
                        HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource rgvHeaderCellStyle}"
                        HeaderTextAlignment="Center"
                        TextAlignment="Center"
                        Width="Auto">

    <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource rgvCellStyle}"
               TargetType="telerik:GridViewCell">
            
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="telerik:GridViewCell">

                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                ToolTipService.Placement="Bottom"
                                ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding CreditIssuesText, Converter={StaticResource NewLineConverter}}">

                            <Image Source="/HubSilverlight;component/Images/status_icon_info.png"
                                   Visibility="{Binding CreditIssuesText, Converter={StaticResource TextToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                   Width="16"
                                   Height="16" />

                        </Border>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            
        </Style>
    </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellStyle>

</telerik:GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...may be this will work in your case..not sure.

```
    <Image Source="DefaultImage.png" Width="16" Height="16" >
        <Image.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip>
                <TextBlock MaxWidth="80" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CreditIssuesText}"></TextBlock>
            </ToolTip>
        </Image.ToolTip>
    </Image>
```

set maxwidth to textblock accoding to your need.thank tou !!

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
&#x0a;
```

for a line break for inline text.  I was able to bind to text with a line break using:

```
TestText = "Some text \r\n with a line break";
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TestText}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding TestText}" />
```

Which produced:

[image]

Comment: Yea, that's one that I've already tried.  It's not working in my scenario.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the fact that it's an `Image` instead of a `TextBlock`.  All the examples I see are typically `TextBlock`.