# How to add a lineBreak in textBlock

Tags: winrt-xaml

It works if I add a lineBreak this way:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,82,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="46" Foreground="LightGreen"  Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="64" Width="1031">

  Credential SetUp <lineBreak/> Start Here

</TextBlock>



So, I want to add lineBreak inside Text="Credential SetUp <lineBreak/> Start Here"  ?

This is not working. am I doing it correctly?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="Credential SetUp&#x0a;Start Here" />
```

From: [Newline in string attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183406/xaml-newline-in-string-attribute)