# How to wrap words in a 2 lines TextBlock?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I use a two lines TextBlock. And I hope to wrap words in it, while each word's height 
should match the height of `TextBlock Height/2`.

For example, the words may be `"Hello Tom! Hello Jack! Hello Rose! Hello John!"`
When they are in the TextBlock, they should look like below:

```
Hello Tom! Hello Jack!
Hello Rose! Hello John!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Style TargetType=“TextBlock”>
    <Setter Property=“TextWrapping” Value=“WholeWord” />
    <!— Determine your TextBlock height and set half height here —>
    <Setter Property=“LineHeight” Value=“50” />
    <Setter Property=“MaxLines” Value”2” />
    <!— Determine the width that gives you two likes of text to display how you’d like it —>
    <Setter Property=“Width” Value=“100” />
    <Setter Property=“TextAllignment” Value=“Left” />

<Style/>
```

Or follow the methods described here

[Newline in string attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183406/newline-in-string-attribute#183435)