# Make multiline text in the WPF TextBox via XAML code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

1- Copy and paste the following code to the **MainWindow.xaml** file.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="Button1" Height="25" Width="100" Content="Press Me" Click="Button1_Click"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Width="400" Height="200" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
</StackPanel>
```

2- Copy and paste the following code to the **code behind** file.

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder myStringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        myStringBuilder.Append("Orange").AppendLine();
        myStringBuilder.Append("").AppendLine();
        myStringBuilder.Append("Apple").AppendLine();
        myStringBuilder.Append("Banana").AppendLine();
        myStringBuilder.Append("").AppendLine();
        myStringBuilder.Append("Plum").AppendLine();
        TextBox1.Text = myStringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

3- Run this project and then press **Button1**.

***My question:***

How can I manage desired result via only XAML code?

(I dont want to use C# code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question: 
    [Newline in string attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183406/newline-in-string-attribute)

contains the answer to your question I believe.

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Width="400" Height="200" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" AcceptsReturn="True" Text="A&#x0a;B" />
```