# Move text in DataGrid Header to new line in WPF

Tags: wpf

What tag do we use to move a text in DataGrid Header to a new line?

E.g I have the following XAML code:

```
 <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="Grid" ColumnHeaderHeight="80">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn  IsReadOnly="True" Header="Hodor" Width="100" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

What tag should I add and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Grid" ColumnHeaderHeight="80">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn  IsReadOnly="True" Header="Line one&#x0a;Line two" Width="100" >
                    
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
         
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I wonder if you could tell me the documentation you took it from?

Comment: "&#x0a;" is used to give new line.

Comment: [ from her](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183406/newline-in-string-attribute)