# How to add a new line in the text from Resources

Tags: c#, wpf

How to add a new line in the text?

I already have a lot of code and I'm looking for the easiest way not to change the overall structure

Resources:

```
<system:String x:Key="MyKey1">Line1 \n Line2</system:String>
```

Code:

```
<TextBlock>
    u<Run BaselineAlignment="Subscript" FontSize="10">lim</Run> - <Run Text="{Binding TextFromMyKey1}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

The text from Resources enters `TextFormMyKey1`

I tested all the solutions and none works:

- `\n`
- pressing enter
- `&#x0a;`

Here it should be noted that the text enters as a parameter in Run

```
<Run Text="{Binding TextFromMyKey1}"/>
```

---

**NOTE for people who do not read the question:**

The replies from the link below **don't work here**

This question is about putting the text in the `<Run>` tag

Link to a question that does not answer my problem [Newline in string attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183406/newline-in-string-attribute)

Comment: I don't think someone has anything to do. Why marked as a duplicate if it is not a duplicate and I clearly indicated that those answers in this situation do not work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that WPF guy, but maybe one of those ideas helps:

- Write the resource really on multiple line, such it looks like:

  ```
  <system:String x:Key="MyKey1">Line1
  Line2</system:String>
  ```
- Maybe your control for visualization of the text is not capable of showing line breaks. Are you sure it can?