# Using backslashes XAML Attribute MultiBinding.ConverterParameter of type string results in escaped backslash

Tags: c#, string, wpf, xaml, escaping

I'm using a string as a MultiBinding.ConverterParameter in a XAML-definition of a WPF-Window. The converter concatenates multiple strings and uses the ConverterParameter as separator between them.
My problem is: when I want to use a CRLF as separator, the XAML-parser somehow escapes my backslashes. So i get "\\r\\n" as parameter in the converter.
I tried the following variants:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource mergeStringsMultiValueConverter}" >
    <MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
        \r\n
    </MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
    <Binding Path="ApprovalJoystick.ExtendedDisplayString" Mode="OneWay"/>
    <Binding Path="ApprovalJoystickActiveText" Mode="OneWay" />
</MultiBinding>
```

and

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource mergeStringsMultiValueConverter}" ConverterParameter="\r\n">
    <Binding Path="ApprovalJoystick.ExtendedDisplayString" Mode="OneWay" />
    <Binding Path="ApprovalJoystickActiveText" Mode="OneWay" />
</MultiBinding>
```

Result is the same.
Is the a way to get the CRLF as I wrote it in XAML (without escaping)?
Or can I write the linebreak in another way in XAML?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `&#10;` and `&#13;` ? Or `&#x0d;&#x0a;`? See [Newline in string attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183406/newline-in-string-attribute)

Comment: This works, should be changed to an answer:
`ConverterParameter="&#x0d;&#x0a;"`
Thanks a lot to @Étienne Laneville
(And sorry for not finding the quoted article)

Comment: created an answer, glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try `&#10;`, `&#13;` or `&#x0d;&#x0a;`. See [Newline in string attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183406/newline-in-string-attribute).